# scraping a website for data for AI virtual assistant

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am currently making an AI virtual assistant in python 3.7. If you are not familiar with the term (virtual assistant), here are some examples, Siri , Google Home, Alexa, Bixby, etc. The AI I am working on  can open and redirect you to a website that will fulfill your command, for example, if I ask for the news it will open cnn, here's the code for opening cnn:

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.cnn.com")
```

However, I want the AI to print the breaking news from  CNN's website. In case you were wondering I have  tried something similar with a lottery website

```
import json
import urllib.request
from pprint import pprint

websource = urllib.request.urlopen ('http://www.masslottery.com/data/json/games/lottery/recent.json')
data = json.loads(websource.read().decode())
pprint(data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include at lease *some* information as to what you need. What do you expect the AI assistant to read from CNN? How should it be formatted? What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Do you just want to scrape site data from CNN?

Comment: W.Dodge thanks for your comment, and to answer your question,  I want a  program that will display the vital info for any website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an RSS feed and most news sites have them so you can easily parse new stories.

For CNN you can check here: http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/ and pick a RSS feed you would like.

Lets say you wanted to here top stories, you would take this http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss from the link repository I initially posted and you would request the data from the page and parse what you want from it, most likely with the python beautifulsoup library, a version 4 tutorial can be found here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

Answer (score 0):

For python you should check out Beautiful Soup and Selenium for Web Automation.

Look into XPath and Css Slectors.

Learn how to use the debugger in your browser.
Ex. Chrome dev tools or firebug...